# Creating ArcGIS tool that can run list of checks?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, python-script-tool

Is it possible to create a tool in ArcMap where by uploading a shapefile, the tool can run a various number of checks/tests (ie intersecting other shapefiles) and flags or highlights conflicting datasets upon initiating?

Maybe even giving a further option of clipping of the shapefile around the flagged dataset?

I’m a student and I’ve found that this might be possible with *arcpy*, however I don’t exactly know the limitations of using this method and even if such a tool could be made.

Comment: What you describe sounds relatively straightforward to do with ArcPy so I recommend reviewing the Online Help on Python Script Tools first and then seeing if you can create one that browses for a shapefile and then prints its name as your first step.

Comment: I second @PolyGeo. What do you mean by "uploading"?

Comment: Sorry, by uploading I mean by selecting a shapefile from a local directory. Similar to what you would do with a tool that requires you to select a shapefile from a folder.

Comment: And thanks PolyGeo, have started looking into it now. Plenty of resources around, just need to find the right example script to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with reading what a script tool is: [What is a script tool?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_a_script_tool/001500000006000000/)

Then check how to [supply parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/GetParameterAsText/03q300000090000000/) to a script and [how they work](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/). Then read how validation works in script tools - you might want to do some checks on the input shapefile before proceeding any further: [Understanding validation in script tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_validation_in_script_tools/00150000002v000000/)

After that you are ready to perform the "checks" as you call on them on the input data (shapefile). You will probably want to [describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Dataset_properties/03q30000008p000000/) it first to learn more about its [properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/FeatureClass_properties/03q30000001r000000/).

You might like [checking the geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Geometry/018z00000070000000/) of the shapefile to make sure it is valid. There are some GP tools available for that such as [Check Geometry (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Check_Geometry/001700000034000000/). If you need to compare shapefile to another, you have the whole [Data Comparison toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Data_Comparison_toolset/001700000003000000/) for that. If you need some serious data review, you might like using the [Data Reviewer extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//0102000000n7000000) in case you have access to this.

For finding out spatial relationships between your shapefile and other datasets, look into the Overlay toolset and the Proximity toolset (both in [Analysis toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Analysis_toolbox/000800000002000000/)).

Comment: +1 but I think tool validation should be left until some proficiency with simpler tool scripting has been achieved.